# Submitting Magento form on page load

Tags: php, jquery, forms, magento

I am working on an extension to integrate a third party API into Magento. The steps included are to fill out a form on our site. When the user clicks submit the API pre-fills a form on their site which the user then approves. A few get string variables are sent over to the page on our site, which trigger a second API call (behind the scenes) that retrieves a token. Once the token is created I am then saving the token to a second hidden form and submitting it via this function:

```
function submitAccount() {

 var formId = 'form-payment-submit';
    var myForm = new VarienForm(formId, true);
    var postUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplacepayment/marketplaceaccount/paymentsetup/') ?>';
    if (myForm.validator.validate()) {
            new Ajax.Updater(
                { success:console.log("form success") }, postUrl, {
                    method:'post',
                    asynchronous:false,
                    evalScripts:false,
                    onComplete:function(request, json) {
                       //submitButtonOn();
                       alert('success!');
                    },
                    parameters: $(formId).serialize(true),
                }
            );
      }
}
```

The function in my module then handles saving the values to the database:

```
public function paymentsetupAction(){

    if(!(empty($_POST['access']))){

                // save tokens to db
                $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$_POST['userid']));

                foreach($collection as $row){
                    $id=$row->getAutoid();
                }
                $collectionload = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->load($id);
                $collectionload->setaccesstoken($_POST['access']);
                $collectionload->setrefreshtoken($_POST['refresh']);
                $collectionload->setstripekey($_POST['key']);
                $collectionload->save(); 



            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your payment information has been sucessfully saved.'));
            $this->_redirect('marketplacepayment/marketplaceaccount/payment');


    }

}
```

The problem is that the tokens are not being saved but no errors are appearing. I can't write any of the info to the page since the submit is via AJAX so I am at a loss as to how to debug. Do you see anything immediately wrong with the paymentsetupAction? Or is there an easier way for me to see why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the $collection section - I was using the wrong database column names:

```
$collectionload = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->load($id);
$collectionload->setaccess_token($_POST['access']);
$collectionload->setrefresh_token($_POST['refresh']);
$collectionload->setstripe_key($_POST['key']);
$collectionload->save();
```

Sorry for the random non important question.